# Determine residues

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)=\frac{sin(\pi z)}{z^4-z^2}$. Now I have to determine the residues of all isolated singularities of $f(z)$. The isolated singularities are $z=1$, $z=-1$ and $z=0$ I think. Then I thought I could use $Res(\frac{g}{f};a)=\frac{g(a)}{f'(a)}$. But if I do that all the residues are 0 and I don't think that's correct. Can anybody help me out? 
I have the same question for the residue of $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-cos(z)}$ in $z=0$.How to determine the residue?

Comment: Your formula for the residue is only correct for a simple pole.  $0$ is a pole of order 2.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE $0$ is a simple pole. But the formula only works when you have a simple pole AND $g(z_0)\neq 0$.

Comment: For your other question, the residue of $\frac{1}{1-\cos{z}}$, expand cosine in a series, and use the definition of the residue.

Comment: @N.S.  Ok I got it now thanks.

Comment: For the second part, note that $\dfrac{1}{1-\cos z}$ is an even function.

Comment: Why does so easily follow that if the singularity is removable the residue is 0?

Answer (score 1):

$$z^4-z^2=z^2(z-1)(z+1)$$

But note that all the poles are simples, since

$$zf(z)=\frac{z\sin\pi z}{z^2(z^2-1)}=\frac{\sin\pi z}{z(z^2-1)}\xrightarrow [z\to 0]{}-1$$

and the other two are trivially simple, for example

$$(z+1)f(z)=\frac{\sin\pi z}{z^2(z-1)}\xrightarrow[z\to\ -1]{}0$$

**Added:** For your last question

$$\cos z=1-\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^4}{24}-O(z^6)\implies \frac1{1-\cos z}=\frac1{\frac{z^2}2\left(1-\frac{z^2}{12}+O(z^4)\right)}=$$

$$=\frac2{z^2}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{12}+\frac{z^4}{144}+\ldots\right)$$

and the residue at $\;z=0\;$ is zero...

Answer (score 1):

$z=1$ is a removable singularity, so the residue is $0$. You cannot use the formula you wrote since $g(z_0) =0$.

$z=-1$ is a removable singularity, so the residue is $0$.

$z=0$ is a simple Pole, but is not in the case your formula works.Going back to the definition

$$Res(f,0)=\lim_{z \to 0} z \times \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^4-z^2}=\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z} \frac{1}{z^2-1}$$ which is easy to calculate.

For $$\frac{1}{\cos(z)-1}$$ $0$ is a pole of order $2$. Use the definition

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \left(\frac{z^2}{\cos(z)-1} \right)' \,.$$

After you derivate, 
$$\frac{1}{\cos(z)-1}=\frac{1+\cos(z)}{-\sin^2(z)}$$
will probably make the limit easier to calculate.

Comment: Why does so easily follow that if the singularity is removable the residue is 0?

Comment: @RoosJansen If the singularity is removable, it follows that all the negative rank terms in the Laurent series are $0$. The residue is one of them.

Comment: @RoosJansen Or, if $g$ is analytic at $z_0$ and $f(z)=g(z)$ near $z_0$, then $$\int_{|z-z_0|=\epsilon} f(z)=\int_{|z-z_0|=\epsilon}g(z)=0$$ the last inequality following from Cauchy Integral Theorem.